# Java, How to compare in generic

Tags: java

I'm learning about binary Tree algorithm but I've got a problem here..

```
public class Binary_tree_list<T> {
    private Node<T> root;
    private int size;

    private static class Node<T> {
        private Node<T> left;
        private Node<T> right;
        private T data;

    ....

        public int compare(Node<T> other) {
            return this.data - other.data;
        }
    }
```

This makes error saying that I can't use  operator `-` for the argument T. What should I do?

Comment: You need to check the `Comparable` interface and see some example of how to impl it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your case, the Type of **T** will matter, but this is not the way you should do.

Your class **T** whatever it will be should have a proper implementation of compareTo or compare method, depends what interface it is implementing.

Have a look at this https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable

Comment: Thanks, I asked such a silly question at that time.